# How to draw a continuous vertical line in an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, drawing, android-view

I want to draw a vertical line for all the child items in a group of an ExpandableListView. My child item is a `TextView`, so I tried to draw a vertical line in every child `TextView`, like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(25, 0, 25, getHeight(), mPaint);
    }
```

But there was a small space between every adjacent items, so the lines of items did not combine into one single line. Just like the items below:

```
group 1
| child 1
| child 2
| child 3
| child 4
group 2
| child 1
| child 2
```

How can I draw a single line instead?

Comment: this is because items are separated with some divider padding (`android:dividerHeight`)

Comment: i called `mExpandableListView.setDividerHeight(0)` but both the group dividers and child dividers are gone, and `mExpandableListView.setChildDivider(null)` did not work either. I can draw the group dividers myself in the layout, but is there a way to set the child dividers height only?

Comment: use both: `elv.setDividerHeight(0);        elv.setChildDivider(null);`